# Excel VBA if statement ignoring loops

Tags: vba, excel, loops, if-statement

I've been trying to get this code to work for weeks. I can get it to 'print' to the first column and row in the table (D4). After that it seems as if it ignores the loop(s) to enter more data in each of the columns and rows thereafter.

I'm trying to get it to compare the number in the first column with a corisponding number in the third row and if they match paste the value of a cell (the 101s) in the same row under the column of the right number. If anyone can see where im going wrong it would be great. I've pasted my worksheet and code below.

Worksheet:

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
3 |     |     |     |  1  |  2  |  3  |
4 |  1  |     | 101 |     |     |     |
5 |  2  |     | 101 |     |     |     |
6 |  3  |     | 101 |     |     |     |
```

VBA Code:

```
Sub Fill()
Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer
For col = 1 To 3
    For row = 1 To 3
        If Cells(3, col + 3) = Cells(row + 3, 1) Then
        Cells(row + 3, col + 3).Value = Cells(row + 3, col + 2)
        End If
    Next row
Next col
End Sub
```

Should result in

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
3 |     |     |     |  1  |  2  |  3  |
4 |  1  |     | 101 | 101 |     |     |
5 |  2  |     | 101 |     | 101 |     |
6 |  3  |     | 101 |     |     | 101 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `col + 2` is meant to be just `3`, i.e. get the value from column C:

```
Sub Fill()
Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer
For col = 1 To 3
    For row = 1 To 3
        If Cells(3, col + 3) = Cells(row + 3, 1) Then
        Cells(row + 3, col + 3).Value = Cells(row + 3, 3)
        End If
    Next row
Next col
End Sub
```

This will be slightly easier to read if you use:

```
Sub Fill()    
    Dim hor As Long
    Dim ver As Long
    For hor = 4 To 6 ' it will be easier to understand if you use the counter
                     ' to refer to the actual column
        For ver = 4 To 6 ' it will be easier to understand if you use the counter
                         ' to refer to the actual row
            If Cells(3, hor).Value = Cells(ver, "A").Value Then
                Cells(ver, hor).Value = Cells(ver, "C").Value
            End If
        Next ver
    Next hor
End Sub
```

---

And, of course, this can be achieved using the following formula in cell D4

```
=IF(D$3=$A4,$C4,"")
```

and copying that formula to D4:F6.

Comment: I tried using ver (for a row counter) and hor (for a column counter) in the past to no avail. TBH this is the practice for my project. When it didn't work, I isolated the problem I was having. The columns A, B & C (where the 101s are in C) will be filled from the web (Lap) data that will be updating regularly from a website. However if that data changes (to another Lap) it deletes the collected data where I want to keep it. I'll keep trying with a separate counter to move columns and rows in the meantime.

Comment: If the `101`s are in column C, change `"B"` in my answer to `"C"` (or, in the first set of code, which is just yours with the `c+2` changed to `2`, change that `2` to `3`)  And the equivalent Excel formula would be `=IF(D$3=$A4,$C4,"")`

Comment: @Grenader65 Have edited the answer (and the question) to reflect your comment that the `101`s are in column C, not column B.  (Actually, I should have noticed that they must have been in column C, because you said cell D4 was correctly populated, and that implies that cell C4 had a `101` in it.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code (Updated code):

```
Sub Fill()
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    For col = 4 To 6
        For row = 2 To 4
            If Cells(row, 1) = Cells(1, col) Then
                Cells(row, col).Value = Cells(row, 3)
            End If
        Next row
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: When I plug and play your code, I get the same result. As in D4 gets filled and no other cells like E5 and F6 (by the values in the reference cells). Shame, when I read your code it works for me but it seems so strange it doesn't loop also. If i simplify the worksheet to avoid empty rows etc i would give the code Sub Fill()
Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer
For col = 1 To 3
    For row = 1 To 3
        If Cells(1, col + 2) = Cells(row + 1, 1) Then
        Cells(row + 1, col + 2).Value = Cells(row + 1, col + 1)
        End If
    Next row
Next col
End Sub

Comment: I found you change the data, I updated the code and it works for me. Please try again with this updated code.